# Django - on_delete=models.PROTECT not working properly

Tags: python, django

Hello friends I need help,

I'm new in python and Django

This time I'm building my app and i'm trying to use `on_delete=models.PROTECT` it works ok but I want to replace my template `ProtectedError` for any message.

How can I do that?

I have something like this:

**grupos models**

```
class grupos(models.Model):
    nombre_grupo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre_puerto = models.ForeignKey(puerto, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo
```

As you can see there's a dependecy, where if I have a `puerto` created it won't let me delete that `puerto` that's fine and that's working but I'm getting the template error and I want a msg instead of that.

Here's my puerto delete views:

Puerto **views.py**

```
def delete(request, id):
    # I want the message here..... (such as messages.warning or something)
    note = get_object_or_404(puerto, pk=id).delete()
    messages.error(request, 'This puerto has been deleted.')
    return redirect('/puertot')
```

for example, I want something like `messages.warning(request, 'You can't delete this because it's being used by grupos')`

**Template error:**

> ProtectedError at /delete/59/ ("Cannot delete some instances of model
>   'puerto' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key:
>   'grupos.nombre_puerto'", ]>)

I've trying to figure out how to manage this but no clue...

How can I do this?

Thanks...!

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it now and tell me if the ProtectedError exception is better handled now or not ?

Comment: yes! worked as expected, thank you! @PrakharTrivedi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **try/except** for the exception problem.

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError

def delete(request, id):

    try :
        note = get_object_or_404(puerto, pk=id).delete()
        messages.error(request, 'This puerto has been deleted.')

    except ProtectedError:
        messages.warning(request, "You can't delete this because it's being used by grupos")

    return redirect('/puertot')
```

Comment: It's not recommended to blanket catch all exceptions. He should do something along the lines of `except ProtectedError`, instead.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim I understand your point, my earlier answer was that only but then I changed for it to be more convenient.Updated it now.